# Как задать белый фон изображения на php?

Tags: php

Не получается задать белый фон, картинка получается на выходе с черным фоном:

```
$img=imagecreatetruecolor(1920,1080);
$background=imagecolorallocate($img, 255,255,255);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так:

`$white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
            imagefill($img, 0, 0, $white);`